# Freeswitch terminates with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: freeswitch, opal

While freeswitch is running and we call 1 client to another client then another client pick the call then code is dumped and throwing following error.

I am trying allocate the memory for that function but nothing happens.

```
Core was generated by `./freeswitch'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0  0x00007fb18e95a771 in H245NegLogicalChannels::FindChannelBySession (
   this=<optimized out>, rtpSessionId=rtpSessionId@entry=0,
    fromRemote=fromRemote@entry=false, anyState=anyState@entry=false)
   at /root/opal/src/h323/h323neg.cxx:1097
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
1097 if (channel != NULL && (rtpSessionId == 0 || channel->GetSessionID() == >rtpSessionId) &&
(gdb)
```

Comment: - segmentation fault is resulted because of memory issue or your program accessing the memory address that are outside of your memory limit. so i want to know what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Actually i am working on support the h323 calls with free-switch.

Comment: Calls is establish between to endpoint but when other endpoint pick the calls then code dumped. because of that. please help related that issuse

Comment: k that means codec not working or codec negotiation is not made perfectly.check your sdp and then let me know.

Comment: are you able to make the same problem?

Comment: my issues is resolved..thank you for support .